# remove top and bottom white lines of an image python

Tags: python, image

I have 2 pngs in which I want to remove extra whitespace on top and below the image.

```
f=pa_files[7]
img = output_dir + "port_level_analysis/" + f
im = Image.open(img)
width, height = im.size
pixels = list(im.getdata())
pixels[0]
```

and I get [image]

as a result.

I select a different image, I get a different result

[image]

they are both pngs. Is there a reason that the pixel info comes out different?

As it impacts further down logic removing whitespace

Comment: The 2nd image is a greyscale image? Look into bit depths of png

Comment: thanks, 2nd is 8bit png, 1st is 32bit png. Need to delve into this deeper